# How to change image urls in a markdown string

Tags: regex, node.js, markdown

I am working on a nodejs CMS where users write blog posts in Markdown locally, after uploading we process the post in an HTML file. Sometimes users will add a picture like `my dog.jpg` to the post by copying the image and writing:

```
![a picture of my dog](my dog.jpg)
```

I use [uslug](https://npmjs.org/package/uslug) to convert all filenames so that `my dog.jpg` becomes `my-dog.jpg`. However I also need to update the link in the blogpost using uslug, because a) otherwise the link would break because we just changed the filename and b) because most markdown parsers for node will skip the above image syntax because of the whitespace (while the image does get previewed in a lot of local Markdown editors, like [Mou](http://mouapp.com/)).

Does anybody know how I can achieve this using regex?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need a lot of slashes:

```
string.replace(/(!\[.*?\]\()(.+?)(\))/g, function(whole, a, b, c) {
    return a + addDashesOrWhatever(b) + c;
});
```

Comment: That does select url, however it also selects the `![](` part (which I can't cut off and append again because op the optional alt). Is it possible to only select the url inside the image tag?

Comment: You can put the prefix and suffix into capturing groups as well, and then access them separately and concatenate the results. I've updated the answer.